# How to gracefully shutdown a Flask application

Tags: python, docker, flask, werkzeug, python-poetry

I have a Flask application which I want to shutdown gracefully. Currently, it is ignoring the `SIGTERM` signal from docker, which leads to a `SIGKILL` signal a few seconds later (after `stop-grace-period`).

I know I can handle the signal using the following code:

```
import signal

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    logging.info(f'Signal handler called with signal {signum}')
    if signum in [signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM]:
        logging.info("Attempting to shutdown gracefully")
        # ...Missing shutdown code...

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
```

But I am missing the code to actually shutdown the app. I tried [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63432682/476260):

```
shutdown_server = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
if shutdown_server is not None:
   shutdown_server()
```

However I get the exception:

```
  File "/app/flask_app/server.py", line 19, in signal_handler
    shutdown_func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/flask-app-9TtSrW0h-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 432, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/flask-app-9TtSrW0h-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 554, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()  # type: ignore
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/flask-app-9TtSrW0h-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 33, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

Apparently, that only works if I am within the context of a request. I don't want to add a `/shutdown` endpoint just for this.

For context, I am defining my app inside a `create_app` [factory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/appfactories/#basic-factories), and starting it with: `poetry run flask run`. Inside my `Dockerfile` I'm using `CMD ["poetry", "run", "flask", "run"]`

How can I gracefully handle the `SIGTERM` signal and shutdown the flask application?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal of: what `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` are your container running?

Comment: Is there a problem getting the SIGKILL?

Comment: And FWIIW, it seems Flask gracefully stops with [`SIGINT`](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4199#issuecomment-426109482), which can be defined as [`STOPSIGNAL SIGINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#stopsignal) in a Dockerfile.